# Ajax success function is not calling jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am making ajax call like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var abc = new Array();
    var title ;
    var start ;
    abc.push({
        title: title,
        start: start
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       ...
    });

    $.ajax({

        url: "EventCalendar_Review",
        success: function(data) {

             console.log(data);

         }

    }); //end of .ajax

}); //end of $(document).ready(function()
```

EventCalender_Review is a java file on the server. While debugging i saw that it goes to server. Where i collect data, but it is not coming inside the success function. I want that that whatever data i get from the server i use it in my script. But success function is not executing. What i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is not executing and the problem is not that you use `date` and `data`? Make sure the URL is correct.

Comment: are you sure that you really get content of an url that is "EventCalendar_Review" ?

Comment: is that code returning a valid HTTP Response i.e. a code 200?

Comment: Are you sure that the request is completed successfully with a response status 200? Probably you can add `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log("error"); console.log(arguments);}`

Comment: I am getting this in the console **GET http://localhost:8080/WIT/faces/EventCalendar_Review 200 OK 5.15s** . Yes url is calling. When i debug my code, my server invoke, means "EventCalendar_Review" get call. Is it issue of data type, may be the data that my server return is in other form.....Perhaps..

Comment: @EvilP Vodun BobTodd Arun P johny. sorry success method is calling but no data is returning. I am getting data null. Why there is no data in the success method?

Comment: @Basit you are passing DATE and trying to log DATA !!!

Comment: no its just a typo mistake here it is `success: function(data)console.log(data); }`

Comment: @EvilP Vodun BobTodd Arun P johny. What i do. I take data from server then use google ApI to convert  it to json format. Here what i am doing `String json = new Gson().toJson(events);response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` . Am i doing something wrong on server side..?

Comment: @EvilP Vodun BobTodd Arun P johny. It came :) I am making mistake on the server side. It should be like this `response.setContentType("application/json");response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");response.getWriter().write(json);`. I was missing the response.getWriter() part. I also add `dataType: "json"`. Otherwise it doesn't come inside the success function. One thing more I am also using error function like `error: function(){..}`. But how can i get in the error function what error comes. what parameter do i pass to my error function? Like if i want in my error function `console.log(error)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the **complete(jqXHR, textStatus)** callback, and see if your request is not in error state with *textStatus*.

Comment: How can i use **complete(jqXHR, textStatus)** call back in my code?

Comment: `$.ajax({

        url: "EventCalendar_Review",
        success: function(data) {

             console.log(data);

         },
      complete: function(request, textStatus){
     console.log(textStatus); 
 }
    })`

Answer (score 1):

- Your URL seems to be abit akward, but maybe it works.
- You are also passing `date` and trying to log `data`.
- Does it return data ?
- Does it return a valid response (200 Status Code ) ?

Ensure that this will not work for you and respond please !